# Will I lose ranking if I redirect domain A to a page on domain B?

Tags: seo, google, redirects

Basically, domain A is a single-page application and I want to redirect it to an identical page on domain B. I was wondering if the new page on domain B will rank just like how domain A ranked? or am I going to lose some/substantial organic traffic?

Answer (score 1):

If the content is the same and you use a 301 redirect, yes, it should rank the same eventually - it can take some time for search engines to fully "transfer" these rankings because they need to reindex the new page/website, understand the new content (even to see that it is the same), learn to "trust" the new page, redirect the existing backlinks, etc.

From what you are describing, it looks like a very simple transfer and if domain A already has some organic traffic, this change should happen quickly (maybe a few months to see most of the traffic to come back).

A few things to keep in mind:

1. This 301 redirect should stay live for at least 18 months
2. Don't lose control of the old domain, you don't want someone buying it and using it for something else (it might undo this work)
3. Review the [Change of Address tool documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9370220?hl=en), it might be relevant to your case

Answer (score 0):

If you are redirection domain A - x page to y page that is fine but if you are redirection domain A - X page to Domain B - Y page then obliviously you will loss the Google ranking.

You can't redirect Domain A page to Domain B page because both the domains are different and the would not work good for your present Google ranking.

I would like to share some points which you have to consider while doing any 301 redirection.

When you can do the redirection?
1. 404 error - If you have deleted any page from Domain A and not it is showing 404 error (page not found) then you can redirect this page on the another page which is more relevant to the deleted page.

2. URL changed - If you changed the URL of the any page, in this case you have redirect the old page on new page. Like for example:
   http://www.domaina.com/seo (old URL)
   http://www.domaina.com/search-engine-optimization (new URL)
   here you have changed the URL so in this you have to redirect old url to the new url.

The redirection will help you to shift your page link juice to another page which is more relevant.